# Getting org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML

Tags: hibernate, netbeans, hibernate-mapping

I am using NetbeansIDE 7.2. and pgAdmin III PostgreSQL 9.2 with Database name "StudentReports".

I know a little of Hibernate and generating JasperReports using native SQL through JDBC Connection, but I am new to generating JasperReports connecting thru Hibernate Connection which this tutorial shows.

I am getting o`rg.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML Error` and *never* made a successful Hibernate Connection test, an error pops up saying "Could not parse mapping document from resource com/report/mappings/Department.hbm.xml", after following this tutorial ["JasperReports with Hibernate - Module 1"](http://bhaskaravignesh-j2ee.blogspot.com/2010/07/jasperreports-with-hibernate.html) and [JasperReports with Hibernate - Module 2](http://bhaskaravignesh-j2ee.blogspot.com/2010/07/jasperreports-with-hibernate-module-2.html). It has 2 Modules. But I did a little modifications on its data access object (DAO) files and I just wanted to have a Department Records. Also, I used a different version of Hibernate and Jasper Reports Package and iReport Plugin for Netbeans which are Hibernate Release 4.1.9 and Jasper Reports 5.0.1 and iReport-4.5.0. I have added all of the jar files of it to my project's Library.

This is my first time handling hibernate mapping xml files and data access object files.

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>   Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
>       at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:109)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:478)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:474)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:647)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:730)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2115)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2087)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2067)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2020)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1935)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1914)
>       at com.report.dao.DepartmentDAO.saveDepartment(DepartmentDAO.java:20)
>       at com.report.test.AddDepartments.main(AddDepartments.java:20)
>   Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 15 of document  : The element type "hibernate-mapping" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "". Nested exception: The element type "hibernate-mapping" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".
>       at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:78)
>       ... 12 more
>   Java Result: 1

These are my codes:

**Department.java**

```
package com.report.beans;
  public class Department  implements java.io.Serializable {

 private int id;
 private String name;

public long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD         3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"> 
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url"> jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/StudentReports</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">postgres</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
   <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>    

<mapping resource="com/report/mappings/Department.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
```

**Department.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.report.beans.Department"  lazy="false" table="Department" schema="dbo"      catalog="StudentReports"/>
        <id name="id" type="long">
        <column name="ID" />
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="string">
        <column name="name" length="100" not-null="true" unique="true" />
    </property>
```

**DepartmentDAO.java**

```
package com.report.dao;

import com.report.beans.Department;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class DepartmentDAO{


public String saveDepartment(Department department)
{

    SessionFactory sessionF = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionF.openSession();

//  This is the code I modified. I didn'y use HibernateSessionFactory
//  Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
    String Result = "";

    try
    {
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(department);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        Result = "Department Saved Successfully";
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        session.close();
        Result = "Department was not saved due to the above Exception";
    }

    return Result;
}
}
```

**AddDepartments.java**

```
package com.report.test;

import com.report.beans.Department;
import com.report.dao.DepartmentDAO;

public class AddDepartments
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Department electronics = new Department();
        electronics.setName("Electronics Engineering");

    Department computerScience = new Department();
        computerScience.setName("Computer science Engineering");

    Department civil = new Department();
        civil.setName("Civil Engineering");


    String Result1 = new DepartmentDAO().saveDepartment(electronics);
        System.out.println(Result1);

    String Result2 = new DepartmentDAO().saveDepartment(computerScience);
        System.out.println(Result2);

    String Result3 = new DepartmentDAO().saveDepartment(civil);
        System.out.println(Result3);
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error shows

> The element type "hibernate-mapping" must be terminated by the matching end-tag

Therefore add a matching closing tag for this element in `Department.hbm.xml` as expected by the XML parser

```
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Similarly add a closing `hibernate-configuration` element in `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: I see. It had actually solved the error. Thank you so much. I I am now connected to my Hibernate Connection.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes is because you have a break line in the start of XML file.

```
<!--Sure that no exists break line here.-->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping> 
    <class name="hibernate.Person" table="PEOPLES">
        <id name="id" column="ID">
            <generator class="foreign"> 
            <param name="property">adress</param> 
        </generator>
        </id>

        <property name="name" /> 

        <one-to-one name="adress" cascade="persist, delete"/> 
    </class> 
</hibernate-mapping>
```